# how can i do object detection in c#.net using opencv?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to do a project "Object detection" I selected the language C#.net. Can I use OpenCV library to do this project in c#.net?

If so, what will be the steps and what are the functions in OpenCV library can I use?

Please anybody help me...

thanx

Comment: Is c#4.0 really the right tag for this question?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCVDotNet has been dormant for a while - I would recommend [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/). The example project includes a shape detection sample that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Google reveals [OpenCVDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/).